# Trying to create a library for com using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, com

I've been having some trouble with this topic for awhile and thought I'd ask the community for advice.  I just can't seem to find anything geared towards vb.net online, and my C# knowledge is not sharp or complete enough to make sense of the C# examples.

I'd like to be able to create a class library in vb.net for use in VBA macros elsewhere.  In particular, in Excel and a terminal emulator we use.  I'm trying to start simple, and work my way up from there.  For the moment, here is the test code I'm trying to use:

```
Public Class ComTest

    Public Function SayHello() As String
        Return "Hello"
    End Function

End Class
```

Under properties > application > assembly information I've checked the "make assembly com visible" box.

When I try to set a reference to this dll using the VBA editor I get the error message that I can't add a reference to the specified file.  If I try to declare the function as such:

```
Private Declare Function SayHello Lib "C:\SomePath\ComTest.dll" ()
```

I get a Run-time error '453':  Can't find DLL entry point SayHello in C:\SomePath\ComTest.dll

I vaguely understand that declaring the function would be the approach to take with a "regular" DLL containing unmanaged code.  The former would actually be creating a COM component.  Given the choice, I'd take the former and just set a reference to the file.  In particular, I'd like it to be registration free, but I think I understand that part if I can just get it to work as a com component for VBA.

So if anyone can provide some advice on either method, I'd be most thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare a function when you use COM. COM was made so that you wouldn't need to do that.

Your application should have an assembly name in the property pages (in the same dialog where you've set the "make assembly com visible" check box). That name is used to instantiate your object with:

```
Dim obj, msg
Set obj = CreateObject("YourAssemblyName.ComTest")
msg = obj.SayHello()
```

If you need to early bind your library, just add it to your project references (it should appear listed in the components list). Then you can do:

```
Dim obj As YourAssemblyName.ComTest
Dim msg As String
Set obj = New YourAssemblyName.ComTest
msg = obj.SayHello()
```

Comment: VBA won't allow me to set the reference to the dll though, and trying the CreateObject method resulted in Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object.  For what its worth, I'd much rather early bind than late bind as well, if possible.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you need to early bind, just reference your library in your project and then do Set obj = New YourAssemblyName.ComTest. You cannot use Declare Function with COM objects: it will simply not work.

Comment: I just changed the answer to reflect this. You need to successfully build your VB.Net library project for it to register as a COM object.